# Using Automapper to map from dynamic/JObject to arbitrary types without creating multiple maps

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, automapper

In an ASP.NET Core controller method, which has a parameter of type `dynamic`, I would like to map using Automapper as shown below. The method looks like this:

```
public IActionRsult Post([FromBody] dynamic model) {
  // Skip validation
  switch(model.src) {
    case "employer"
      var employerVM = _mapper.Map<EmployerViewModel>(model.data);
      // Work with mapped object
    break;
    case "employee"
      var employeeVM = _mapper.Map<EmployeeViewModel>(model.data);
      // Work with mapped object
    break;
  }
}
```

where `EmployerViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class EmployerViewModel {
   public string CompanyName {get; set;}
   public string CompanyAddress {get; set;}
}
```

and `EmployeeViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel {
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public bool Ready {get; set;} 
}
```

It receives JSON data from the client side, which may look like this:

```
{
  "src": "employer",
  "data": {
    "CompanyName": "Pioneers Ltd.",
    "CompanyAddress": "126 Schumacher St., London" 
  }
}
```

or this:

```
{
  "src": "employee",
  "data": {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Ready": true
  }
}
```

Now everything works fine except for boolean properties, which are always set to false no matter what the value in JSON is. I have JSON input formatter, which constructs the instances in the parameter. I've checked the type of the instances and found them to be Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Any idea how I can get bools to behave correctly?

I would like to continue supporting mapping an arbitrary number of destination classes using the `TDestination IMapper.Map<TDestination>(object source)` (see [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/IMapper.cs#L14)) without having to explicitly construct AutoMapper maps for each. Any hint how this can be achieved?

P.S. I'm using AutoMapper 6.2.1 and ASP.NET Core 1.1.3

Comment: It works with ExpandoObject for example, so it's a question of how model gets put together.

Comment: The JSON Input formatter packs a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject instance inside the dynamic parameter, model

Comment: Then that's what you should be investigating. As far as AM is concerned, it works.

Comment: Edited question to emphasize the JObject resulting from the JSON input formatter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `JObject` wraps its content in `JValue`, so it cannot work by default with AM which of course expects the actual values. So you have to let AM know how to map a `JValue`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<JValue, object>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Value);
```

Comment: That was it!. Thanks. It worked after adding this converter config to the AutoMapper mapping profile